# Как прописать кнопку в css?

Tags: html, css

ширину и высоту кнопки лучше прописывать с помощью padding или width и height?

Comment: Зависит от конкретной ситуации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще лучше не писать ничего в `width/height`, только в крайнем случае и для некоторых элементов, нужно не забывать про адаптивность верстки, хотя бы малейшую, кнопку я бы точно делал через `padding`.

Comment: width/height никак не мешают адаптивности

Comment: Ну если прописывать для каждого расширения, то да, а так мне кажется кнопку проще сделать через padding, чем задавать размеры, я не верстальщик, но я не видел таких кнопок и сам не делаю, в основном на сайтах делают через `padding`, разве что исключительная ситуация, когда размер кнопки не должен зависеть от текста.

Comment: вот я просто думаю если в кнопку добавится текст, тогда она не сломается если на padding

Comment: От дизайна зависит, если обычная кнопка, то она просто растягивается и за счет `padding` она будет выглядеть так же, просто шире/уже, так обычно делают.

Comment: окей, спасибо:)